# Get user's highest score from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a feeling this is a very simple question but maybe i'm having brain fart right now and just can't seem to figure out how to go about it.

I have a MySQL table structure like below

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| id |     date     |  score  |  speed  |  user_id  |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |  2016-11-17  |  2      | 133291  |     17    |
|  2 |  2016-11-17  |  6      | 82247   |     17    |
|  3 |  2016-11-17  |  6      | 21852   |     17    |
|  4 |  2016-11-17  |  1      | 109338  |     17    |
|  5 |  2016-11-17  |  7      | 64762   |     61    |
|  6 |  2016-11-17  |  8      | 49434   |     61    |
```

Now i can get a particular user's best performance by doing this

```
SELECT * 
FROM performance 
WHERE user_id = 17 AND date = '2016-11-17'
ORDER BY score desc,speed asc LIMIT 1
```

This should return the row with ID = 3. Now what I want is a single query to run to be able to return that 1 such row for each unique user_id in the table. So the resulting result would be something like this

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| id |     date     |  score  |  speed  |  user_id  |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|  3 |  2016-11-17  |  6      | 21852   |     17    |
|  6 |  2016-11-17  |  8      | 49434   |     61    |
```

Also further more, can I have another question within this same query that would further sort this eventual resulting table by the same criteria of sort (score desc, speed asc). Thanks

Comment: I think you need to group

Comment: group is not working as it doesn't take account of the order clause

Comment: Does the max score record always have the min speed associated with it?

Comment: @xQbert how `HAVING MAX(score)` without a comparasion will filter rows?

Comment: Please specify the expected result more clearly. Also, include sample data to your question, or even better, create an example at sqlfiddle

Comment: @baao how `HAVING MAX(score)` without a comparasion will filter rows?

Comment: I added tag `greatest-n-per-group`. This type of question has been answered hundreds of times.

Comment: By the way, in your WHERE clause you are using a comma where you should use `AND`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select p.* 
from performance p
where p.date = '2016-11-17' and
      p.id = (select p2.id
              from performance p2
              where p2.user_id = p.user_id and p2.date = p.date
              order by score desc, speed asc
              limit 1
             );
```

This should be able to take advantage of an index on `performance(date, user_id, score, speed)`.

Comment: this version is better than using variables?

Comment: @Gordon Thanks as this gives me exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Is easy using variable to emulate `row_number() over (partition by Order by)`

Explanation:

1. First create two variables in the subquery.
2. Order by `user_id` so when user change the `@rn` reset to 1
3. Order by `score` desc, `speed` asc so each row will have a row_number, and the one you want always will have `rn = 1`
4. `@rn :=` you change `@rn` for each row

   - if you have a new `user_id` then `@rn` is set to 1
   - otherwise `@rn` is set to `@rn+1`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/JRJ15225)**

```
SELECT `id`, `date`, `score`, `speed`, `user_id`
FROM (
        SELECT *,
               @rn := if(@user_id = `user_id`, 
                         @rn + 1 , 
                         if(@user_id := `user_id`,1,1)
                        ) as rn           
        FROM Table1
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @user_id := 0, @rn := 0) as param
        WHERE date = '2016-11-17' 
        ORDER BY `user_id`, `score` desc, `speed` asc
     ) T
where T.rn =1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Wow this give me exactly what I want. Please can you give some explanation to your code so I get an idea of what you were doing. First time coming across variables and row_number() too

Comment: I add more explanation. You can google `Sql ROW_NUMBER()` the problem is mysql doesnt have that function, so you have to use variable to emulate it. Let me now if is more clear now.

Comment: I just added a bunch of more records and tried the query again and i'm getting more than 1 row for each user_id

Comment: Update your question with the new data, or update the sql demo and send me the new link.

Comment: I really hope you can update the question or send me the rextester link to give me the chance to find what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

For  mysql

You can try with a double in subselect and group by

```
  select * from    performance
  where (user_id, score,speed ) in (

            SELECT user_id, max_score, max(speed)
            FROM performance 
            WHERE (user_id, score) in (select user_id, max(score) max_score
                                       from performance 
                                       group by user_id)
            group by user_id, max_score
  );
```

Comment: The problem is i'm getting their performance not just by their score but by their score and speed

Comment: @scaisEdge I think he mean `max(score)` but in case of tie `min(speed )` like `score =6` for `user=17`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza   . i have try with two inner subselect and group by

Comment: @scaisEdge yeah Juan is right. I can do this for a single user_id and just do LIMIT 1 at the end. But what i'm looking for is a query that returns the best performance for each user_id

Comment: @OlanrewajuLaxLawal   i have update the answer  and i think my new answer  wotrk for all user ..and for max(score) and when equals for max(speed)  .. take a look ..

Comment: @scaisEdge please review your code again as there seems to be an extra closing bracket. Doubt this would work still tho